# Dynamically create dictionary in for loop containing APIs

Tags: python, dictionary

Newish to python and programming. How can I create a dictionary using for loop that contains two APIs (one pulls ticker symbols from a dictionary of S&P 500 companies, and other is yahoo_finance to pull corresponding market cap data) and additionally can be updated to replace existing data.

```
import sp500
from yahoo_finance import Share

tickers = {}

for d in sp500:
   for k, v in tickers.items():
      retrieveticker = d['symbol']
      yahoodata = Share(retrieveticker)
      dict = {retrieveticker,yahoodata.get_market_cap(retrieveticker)}
      tickers.update(dict)

print tickers
```

In other words. Main goal is to go down the list of sp500 companies, find its corresponding market cap, and create dictionary with ticker as the key, and market cap as its value.

Comment: You are creating a set, not a dict...

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is unpack your items into the `{}` so it creates a dict instead of a set, like this:

```
yahoo = {'key': 'value'}
retrieveticker = {'key2': 'value2'}
a_dict = {**retrieveticker, **yahoo}
a_dict
{'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

Also, don't use `dict` for a variable name.

I don't have `yahoo_finance`, but this is what it would look like in your code:

```
for d in sp500:
   for k, v in tickers.items():
      retrieveticker = d['symbol']
      yahoodata = Share(retrieveticker)
      a_dict = {**retrieveticker, **yahoodata.get_market_cap(retrieveticker)}
      tickers.update(a_dict)
```

Assuming that `retrieveticker` and `yahoodata.get_market_cap(retrieveticker)` are both dicts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. retrieveticker would be the symbol...so lets say AAPL (pulled from sp500 dictionary). I would use that ticker in a corresponding API call. Ideally, i would want the dictionary to have all 500 of the S&P companies as the keys and their corresponding market caps as the values.

Comment: Oops, indeed I did. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want to add the values to the dictionary like this:

```
tickers[retrieveticker] = yahoodata.get_market_cap(retrieveticker)
```

Instead of the two lines you have at the end of each iteration of your for loop.